# Copying worksheets from multiple workbooks into existing worksheets in a different workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template workbook with tab names of "Extract 1, Extract 2, Extract 3" etc and a main Summary page that contains formulas that rely on all of these tabs. I also have a number of workbooks (22) that each contain one worksheet with a data extract in them. I need to be able to loop through these workbooks and copy the sheets over without the need to remove and insert a new tab (needs to use existing tabs). Initially I had this:

```
    Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\hill\Desktop\Summary Doc Output Files\Summary Doc Output Files\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
  Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
     For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
     Filename = Dir()
  Loop
 Dim x As Integer

End Sub
```

but this only inserts new tabs and does not use the existing tab structure in place.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the 22 workbooks only have 1 sheet, you don't need to loop through each of those sheets. Also, you can just copy the contains of the sheet onto whichever sheet you desire in your Mainbook.

so replace,

```
  For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
  Next Sheet
```

With

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Extract 1").UsedRange.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
```

*Note: The use of `.UsedRange` assumes your data structure in each worksheet is the same as in the `Extract` sheets and that there are no merged cells.*

And assuming you that copy the first workbook to `Extract 1` sheet and so on you can place a counter in your macro to paste each workbook into a different sheet.

```
Sub GetSheets()
Dim x As Integer, wb as Workbook

Path = "C:\Users\hill\Desktop\Summary Doc Output Files\Summary Doc Output Files\"

Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")

x = 1
Do While Filename <> ""

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Extract " & x).UsedRange.Value = wb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value    

    wb.Close false

    x = x + 1

    Filename = Dir()

Loop


End Sub
```